# Jest encountered an unexpected token for Ag-Grid unit testing

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ag-grid, vscode-extensions, ts-jest

#### Reproducible Scenario

run 'npx jest' with

- "@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model": "^30.0.6",
- "@ag-grid-community/core": "^30.0.6",
- "@ag-grid-community/styles": "^30.0.6",

#### Test suite failed to run

Jest encountered an unexpected token

Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

Here's what you can do:
• If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
• If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
• To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
• If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
• If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
For information about custom transformations, see:
https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

Details:

C:\repo\project\node_modules@ag-grid-community\core\dist\esm\es6\main.mjs:15
export { ColumnFactory } from "./columns/columnFactory.mjs";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

5 |
6 | import * as vscode from 'vscode';

> 7 | import { GridOptions, Grid } from "@ag-grid-community/core";
> | ^

at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1496:14)
at Object. (src/test/unit/GridUtils.test.ts:7:1)

#### Jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
"transform": {
'^.+\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx|mjs)$': ['ts-jest',
        {
        diagnostics: false,
        },
    ],
},
transformIgnorePatterns: [
'/node_modules/(?!(@ag-grid-community|@ag-grid-enterprise|ag-grid-react|ag-grid-enterprise|ag-grid-community)/)',
],
testEnvironment: 'node',
testRegex: '/src/test/unit/.*\.(test|spec)?\.(ts|tsx)$',
moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node', 'mjs'],
reporters: [
        'default', ['jest-junit', { outputName: 'unit-test-results.xml' }],
    ],
};
```

#### Environment:

Windows 10, VSCode, NPM
AG Grid version: X.X.X
30.0.6

Browser:
VsCode WebWiew/IFrame

Language:
TypeScript:5.1.6
ES6

Tried using recommended sample resovler and removed transformIgnorePatterns by AG-Grid community but the problem is not resolved.

## jest.config.js

```
/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
module.exports = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  resetMocks: true,
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [],
  resolver: '<rootDir>/myResolver.ts',
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx|mjs)$": [
        "ts-jest"
    ],
  }
};
```

## new file: myResolver.ts

```
module.exports = (request, options) => {
    return options.defaultResolver(request, {
        ...options,
        packageFilter: pkg => {
            const packageName = pkg.name;
            const agDependency = packageName.startsWith("@ag-grid");
            return {
                ...pkg,
                // default to use the CommonJS ES5 entry point for Jest testing with AG Grid
                main: agDependency ? './dist/cjs/es5/main.js' : pkg.module || pkg.main,
            };
        },
    });
};
```

### repo to reproduce the issue

[sample](https://github.com/grantdaigh/Ag-grid-Module-Jest-Unit-Testing-Problem-Demo)